# How do I use the same variable in one function with another function, without making that variable Global?

Tags: python, variables, global

How can I take one variable from one function and use it in another function without having to make that variable global?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have basically two choices.

One is to pass it to the second function as a parameter. (If you want the first function to see changes to the value, it needs to be a reference type (e.g. a dict/list) and you have to not overwrite the object, only modify it (e.g. `a.append(b)` rather than `a = a + [b]`).

The second is to define a class that can be used as a singleton. Technically, this is still defining something 'globally', but it lets you keep things grouped:

```
class FooSingleton(object):
    class_var = "foo"

def func1():
    FooSingleton.class_var = "bar"

def func2():
    print(FooSingleton.class_var)
```

(You could also do this with a `dict` instead of a class; matter of preference.)

Answer (score 2):

have the function take a parameter, and pass that parameter in.

```
def one_function():
  one_variable = ''
  return one_variable

def another_function(a_param):
  # do something to a_param
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically possible and may be used, e.g. for memoisation (but then it is usually hidden behind a decorator and only implemented by people who are sure they do the right thing even though they might still feel a bit bad about it):

```
def g():
    if not hasattr(g, "x"):
        g.x = 0
    return g.x

g()
# 0

g.x = 100
g()
# 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closure to handle this, or more natural is to define both functions as methods of a class and the  "global" variable as member of the class.